# NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'toDouble'. flutter

Tags: flutter, api, rest, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I'm trying to call an API.
This is my model :

```js
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hisselist = hisselistFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<ResultClass> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"], result: json["result"].map<ResultClass>((x) => ResultClass.fromJson(x)).toList(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": result.map((x) => x.toJson()),
  };
}

class ResultClass {
  ResultClass({
    required this.rate,
    required this.lastprice,
    required this.lastpricestr,
    required this.hacim,
    required this.hacimstr,
    required this.text,
    required this.code,
  });

  double rate;
  double lastprice;
  String lastpricestr;
  double hacim;
  String hacimstr;
  String text;
  String code;

  factory ResultClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResultClass(
    rate: json["rate"].toDouble(),
    lastprice: json["lastprice"].toDouble(),
    lastpricestr: json["lastpricestr"],
    hacim: json["hacim"].toDouble(),
    hacimstr: json["hacimstr"],
    text: json["text"],
    code: json["code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rate": rate,
    "lastprice": lastprice,
    "lastpricestr": lastpricestr,
    "hacim": hacim,
    "hacimstr": hacimstr,
    "text": text,
    "code": code,
  };
}
```

This is where i call the API

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/apis/hisselist.dart';

class Hisseler extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hisseler({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Hisseler> createState() => _HisselerState();
}

class _HisselerState extends State<Hisseler> {

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.collectapi.com/economy/hisseSenedi');
  var counter;
  Hisselist? hisseResult;

  Future callHisse() async {
    try{
      Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey 3xxx'
      };
      final response = await http.get(url,headers:requestHeaders);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);

        if(mounted);
        setState(() {
          counter = result.result.length;
          hisseResult = result;
        });
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    callHisse();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
            'Hisseler'
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: counter != null ?

          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: counter,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].code??""),
                    subtitle: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].text??""),

                  ),
                );
              }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(

          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error.
I'm using same structure from same api website in the same app but other api has no double in it.
[image]

How can i fix this? Thanks for your help

**Api response(Its longer i had to cut because of characters limit here) :

```js
{
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "rate": 1.63,
            "lastprice": 62.4,
            "lastpricestr": "62,40",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺6.338.850.855,10",
            "min": 61.25,
            "minstr": "61,25",
            "max": 63.35,
            "maxstr": "63,35",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "THYAO - TURK HAVA YOLLARI",
            "code": "https:THYAO"
        },
        {
            "rate": -0.7,
            "lastprice": 10,
            "lastpricestr": "10,00",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺2.494.844.604,08",
            "min": 9.89,
            "minstr": "9,89",
            "max": 10.39,
            "maxstr": "10,39",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "AKBNK - AKBANK",
            "code": "https:AKBNK"
        },
        {
            "rate": -3.2,
            "lastprice": 5.44,
            "lastpricestr": "5,44",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺2.444.674.050,01",
            "min": 5.39,
            "minstr": "5,39",
            "max": 5.76,
            "maxstr": "5,76",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "YKBNK - YAPI VE KREDI BANK.",
            "code": "https:YKBNK"
        },
        {
            "rate": -0.08,
            "lastprice": 24.22,
            "lastpricestr": "24,22",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺1.993.997.946,36",
            "min": 23.88,
            "minstr": "23,88",
            "max": 24.5,
            "maxstr": "24,50",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "SISE - SISE CAM",
            "code": "https:SISE"
        },
        {
            "rate": -1.91,
            "lastprice": 23.68,
            "lastpricestr": "23,68",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺1.903.546.516,50",
            "min": 23.3,
            "minstr": "23,30",
            "max": 24.26,
            "maxstr": "24,26",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "SAHOL - SABANCI HOLDING",
            "code": "https:SAHOL"
        },
        {
            "rate": 1.91,
            "lastprice": 24.56,
            "lastpricestr": "24,56",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺1.878.629.757,06",
            "min": 23.84,
            "minstr": "23,84",
            "max": 24.76,
            "maxstr": "24,76",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "ASELS - ASELSAN",
            "code": "https:ASELS"
        },
        {
            "rate": 4.47,
            "lastprice": 9.81,
            "lastpricestr": "9,81",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺1.660.601.149,10",
            "min": 9.35,
            "minstr": "9,35",
            "max": 9.9,
            "maxstr": "9,90",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "PETKM - PETKIM",
            "code": "https:PETKM"
        },
        {
            "rate": -1.77,
            "lastprice": 17.75,
            "lastpricestr": "17,75",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺1.636.411.291,63",
            "min": 17.62,
            "minstr": "17,62",
            "max": 18.37,
            "maxstr": "18,37",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "GARAN - GARANTI BANKASI",
            "code": "https:GARAN"
        },
        {
            "rate": -0.19,
            "lastprice": 52.6,
            "lastpricestr": "52,60",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺1.514.105.128,80",
            "min": 51.8,
            "minstr": "51,80",
            "max": 53.55,
            "maxstr": "53,55",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "SASA - SASA POLYESTER",
            "code": "https:SASA"
        },
        {
            "rate": -3.09,
            "lastprice": 5.96,
            "lastpricestr": "5,96",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺1.486.079.838,32",
            "min": 5.96,
            "minstr": "5,96",
            "max": 6.23,
            "maxstr": "6,23",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "ISCTR - IS BANKASI (C)",
            "code": "https:ISCTR"
        },
        {
            "rate": -3.01,
            "lastprice": 3.54,
            "lastpricestr": "3,54",
            "hacim": "",
            "hacimstr": "₺1.374.459.094,21",
            "min": 3.49,
            "minstr": "3,49",
            "max": 3.7,
            "maxstr": "3,70",
            "time": "18:09",
            "text": "EKGYO - EMLAK KONUT GMYO",
            "code": "https:EKGYO"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you print `response` and include on question

Comment: Im getting only NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance method 'toDouble'.
I/flutter (13234): Receiver: ""
I/flutter (13234): Tried calling: toDouble() in console and it stuck at CircularProgressIndicator. I check api with false apikey, api is responding in postman too.

Comment: Sorry we cant test it because the api, it would be better if you include postam response on question

Comment: Are you asking api response in my app, or in general?

Comment: both will be same I hope, you can include postman data

Comment: I added the response, but its 6725 line, i had to cut off it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with `double hacim`, it is getting string response like  `"hacim": "",`.

It would better to use `.tryParse` instead of `toDouble()`

Remove  `hacim: json["hacim"].toDouble()`  and Do it like

```dart
   hacim: double.tryParse(json["hacim"]) ?? 0.0,
```

Also better do it for others double as well.

Comment: now it says on console : type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: I added  .toString to fix the other issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the jsonString correctly to `double`. The `double` class has a `double? tryParse(str)` method to parse `string` into `double`.

```dart
double hacimDouble = double.tryParse(json['hacim']??'0.0') ?? 0.0;
```

And, when you want to use `hacimDouble`, then do `hacimDouble.toString()`.